# Почему "хлопчато-БУМАЖНЫЙ"?

Tags: этимология

Хлопковую ткань иначе называют хлопчато-бумажной. Но при чем тут бумага? На ум приходит ткань бумазея, но она как бы тоже не имеет отношения к бумаге.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хлопчатобумажная ткань - слитно пишется, потому что  из хлопчатой бумаги:   http://lifecity.com.ua/?id=4360&l=knowledge&mod=view

Кстати, бумазея- то же самое,хлопок. Слово bombazine образовано от устаревшего французского bombasin, которым первоначально обозначали шёлк, но впоследствии применяли и к шёлковому дереву или хлопку. Бомбазин был сделан в Англии при Елизавете I. В начале XIX столетия было налажено его широкое производство в Норидже.(Википедия)